# Elastic Search pipeline search queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to pipeline multiple queries into Elastic search. My main problem is that when I receive the results I want to be able to know the which was the query that generated the result. In pseudo-code I would like to do something like following

```
query1="James Bond"
query2="Sean Connery"
query3="Charlie Chaplin"

pipeline=new ElasticSearchPipeline()
pipeline.add(query1);pipeline.add(query2);pipeline.add(query3)

pipeline.execute()
jamesBondResults=pipeline.getResultsForQuery(query1)
seanConneryResults=pipeline.getResultsForQuery(query2)
charleChaplinResults=pipeline.getResultsForQuery(query3)
```

The key feature is that I want to send  avoid the overhead of sending multiple requests on the ES server, but still be able to treat the results as if I had sent the queries one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [multi search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) is exactly what you're looking for.

You can send many queries and the response will contain an array with the responses to each query in the same order:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_msearch -d '
{"index" : "test1"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
{"index" : "test2",}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
'
```

The response array of the above multi search queries will contain two ES responses with the documents from the first and second queries.